# Array of dictionaries with Unity and Firebase database - Get values from key

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

First of all - I am pretty new to Unity.

I am trying to retrieve some data from my firebase database, store the data in an array/list of dictionaries, and then use the array/list to show the data from my server.

**So... My way of trying to do:**

1: Create array of dictionaries to hold my data:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Global
{
   public static Dictionary<string, object>[] offers;
}
```

2: Handle the data from the database, and store it in the array:

```
void Handle_ChildAdded(object sender, ChildChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DatabaseError != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError(e.DatabaseError.Message);
            return;
        }
        // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
        if (e.Snapshot.Value != null)
        {
            var dict = e.Snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;

            if (dict != null)
            {
                Debug.Log(dict);
                Global.offers = new Dictionary<string, object>[Global.storesCount+1];
                Global.offers[Global.storesCount] = dict;
                Global.storesCount++;
                hasHaded = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

So now I have alle the snapshots from my database in my Global.offers array. The struckture of the snapshot i should get look something likes this: 
[image]

**Time to show the data from my array**

Everything works fine until this point - Because now I need to show the data I just stored in my Global.offers array.
I try to do that with a loop. I loop though the array and search for the keys from my database and Instantiate the data inside a prefab of a gameobject **like this:**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < Global.storesCount; i++)
        {
            Transform scrollViewObj = Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0, (downSize * i) - firstY, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            scrollViewObj.transform.SetParent(scrollContent.transform, false);
            scrollViewObj.transform.Find("Overskift").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = Global.offers[i]["Store"] as string;
            scrollViewObj.transform.Find("Text (1)").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = Global.offers[i]["Headline"] as string;
            scrollViewObj.transform.Find("Text (2)").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Din pris: " + Global.offers[i]["Price"] as string + " kr.";
            scrollViewObj.transform.Find("Text (3)").gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Spar: " + Global.offers[i]["AndresPris"] as string + " kr.";
        }
```

This is where I get the trouble. For some reason Global.offers[i]["Store"] as string == null, witch of course means that I can't instantiate the object. I get this error:

*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
LoadOffers.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/LoadOffers.cs:36)*

It is so weird, because when I try to debug I get some conflicting results:

The length of the array is 19. So it is not empty.

When I try to Debug.Log the array out I get:

System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object][]

But when I search for values with keys like:

```
Debug.Log(Global.offers[0]["Store"]);
```

All I get is null. Am I searching wrong after the values? Or can anyone else see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The Problem

Your main problem is that `Global.offers`
is an array and therefore has a fixed length and can not be enlarged dynamically that simple (you would have to copy the array everytime!)

You kind of tried to solve this in `Handle_ChildAdded` but in the line

```
Global.offers = new Dictionary<string, object>[Global.storesCount+1];
```

what you actually do is creating a new empty(!) array of dictionaries with length `Global.storeCount+1`. You don't copy the current values to a new array.

so after all executions what you get is an array with only `null`. Only the last item of the array will have the content coming from

```
Global.offers[Global.storeCount] = dict;
```

so only the last value will actually be set. It looks somewhat like

```
{null, null, null, null, ..., Dictionary<string, object> }
```

that's why the length is a correct value. Your exception is actually already thrown the moment you try to access

```
Global.offers[0]
```

which is `null`.

---

#### Solution

I would recommend not to use an array at all but instead a `List` which in contrary to the array can grow dynamically

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Global
{
   public static List<Dictionary<string, object>> offers = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
}
```

and than before starting to fill the list by adding all dictionaries you should actually somwhere call

```
Global.offers.Clear();
```

to reset the list otherwise it keeps growing bigger and bigger with every loading of the database. Also if you are absolutely sure you call this only once you might not need this I would always recommend to do it in order to have a clean, in general working solution.

And later add your elements in

```
void Handle_ChildAdded(object sender, ChildChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DatabaseError != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(e.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }
    // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
    if (e.Snapshot.Value != null)
    {
        var dict = e.Snapshot.Value as Dictionary<string, object>;

        if (dict != null)
        {
            Debug.Log(dict);
            Global.offers.Add(dict);
            hasHaded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Later you do access elements in a `List` the same way as in an array

```
Debug.Log(Global.offers[0]["Store"]);
```

---

Note that you also don't need the variable `storeCount` neither in your solution - you could have simply used

```
Global.offers.Length
```

nor in this new solution - you can simply use

```
Global.offers.Count
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will make it short: I love you! So many hours of watching on the same code, fixed with just an other declaration. You are a life saver!