# C# Firebase Database loop through all top level elements and get all json for each element

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I inherited and existing Firebase database that has many problems.  It looks like the db has multiple data structures due to schema changes from early development to production.  I need to migrate it to SQL Server but can’t access the raw json from a backup due to its size (7GB).  .Net can’t read files that large.  My next option is to loop through every element and import each element into an interim SQL db where I can sort through the data and figure out what to do.

The first problem is every top element is different:

[image]

I’m guessing the GUIDs are user IDs.  I have several problems:

1. I see examples online to query but I can’t use specific text to query.

   firebase.Child("dinosaurs");
2. I have to fetch each element one at a time because fetching all elements will return 7GB of data and crash .net.  So how to I start by getting the first element.  Then query to get the next element.  Each being a separate call for firebase

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Value at the Snapshot, it should return an `IDictionary` with the values as lists and nested dictionaries. This allows you to parse and filter the data including casting it to other constructors.
for example:

```
DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                foreach(var child in snapshot.Children)
                {
                    foreach(var i in child.Children)
                    {
                        Debug.Log(i.Value);
                    }
                }
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017554/2301161

If you want to utilize Shallow Requests, which is possible but at this current time is not documented to be a feature on the Unity modules. Instead - you will have to rely on the REST API to make this request: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow

if that is not the intent of your question, then you are most likely interested in pagination which is supported via a Cursor method using "startAt()" and "LimitToFirst()" - documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#filtering_data

If you are using this to exclusively to migrate data, other frameworks are available with better data handling like NodeJS and Python.

Comment: Thanks Digi but this doesn't answer my question.  It's 7+GB of data.  I can't load all that into a dictionary object.  I need a loop.  How about just downloading a list of all top level elements.  Then I can loop through the list from a console app, and with each element make a call to Firebase to fetch the element and all inner json?

Comment: your original question was looping through the data - not how to obtain shallow requests. Which *is* possible. but at this current time is not documented to be a feature on the Unity modules. Instead - you will have to rely on the REST API to make this request: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#shallow

Comment: if that is not the intent of your question, then you are most likely interested in pagination which is supported via a Cursor method using "startAt()" and "LimitToFirst()" - documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data#filtering_data

If you are using this to exclusively to migrate data, other frameworks are available with better data handling like NodeJS and Python.